# How to delete a column which is the primary key in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting an error while trying to delete the primary key column from the table.

- `id` - primary key column
- Table `OLTMS_0B8DF2`

Query

```
ALTER TABLE OLTMS_0B8DF2
DROP CONSTRAINT id;   
GO
```

Error

> Msg 3728, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   'id' is not a constraint.
>
> Msg 3727, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.

Comment: you are trying to remove column or just the constraint ?

Comment: The constraint should have a name. You can find it out in Management Studio.

Comment: thanks i got the constraint name. i deleted constraint then i deleted column.thanks@JohnyL

Comment: can u please provide me query or link to delete the duplicate rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the existing constraint name rather than the column name to drop the constraint.

You can determine the PK constraint name using the SSMS object browser or with the T-SQL script below. A best practice is to explicitly name constraints (e.g. `PK_OLTMS_0B8DF2`) rather than rely on auto-generated constraint names. That makes subsequent DDL easier.

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.key_constraints AS pk
WHERE
    pk.parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'OLTMS_0B8DF2')
    AND type = 'PK';
```

If you have foreign key constraints referencing the table, you'll need to similarly drop those too.